# how to get a json array from php and use its value in android?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

i am trying to get the data from database through a php file and then i want to use that data in android.i have tried a lot but it show me this error:type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray.
followin is my php file and android code.also json array which was return is valid.

```
<?php
require "config.php";
$con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$pro_id=0;

$sql="SELECT user.user_id, current_location.crtloc_lat,current_location.crtloc_lng FROM user INNER JOIN current_location 
where user.user_id=current_location.user_id AND user.pro_id='$pro_id'";


$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die('i cant');

//$result = array();
$abc="";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
$abc=$abc.$row['user_id'].",".$row['crtloc_lat'].",".$row['crtloc_lng']."~";



}
$final = array("result"=>$abc);
//echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));
echo json_encode($final);

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

andoid code

```
 public void searchProfession() {
        //testin work

        String[] stringArray = new String[5];

        //



        try {
            HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

            HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();
            p.setParameter("profession", SearchProfession);
            // Instantiate an HttpClient
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(p);
            String url = "http://abh.netai.net/abhfiles/searchProfession.php";
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Instantiate a GET HTTP method
            try {
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - start");
                //fffffffffffffffffffffffffff
                httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                String result = null;
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                inputStream = entity.getContent();
                // json is UTF-8 by default
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                result = sb.toString();

// return JSON String


                if (inputStream != null) inputStream.close();


                //ffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
                //
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "1"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                        responseHandler);
                // Parse

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("result");

                ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                //testin work
                String[] myarray;

                //till here
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String jsonString = jArray.getString(i);
                    stringArray[i] = e.toString();
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "yourrrrs"+stringArray[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    mylist.add(map);
                }


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - end");

        } catch (Throwable t) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Request failed: " + t.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }

    }
```

My Json : `[[],{"user_id":"77","crtloc_lat":"34.769638","crtloc_lng":"72.361145"},{"user_id‌​":"76","crtloc_lat":"34.769642","crtloc_lng":"72.361160"},{"user_id":"87","crtloc‌​_lat":"33.697117","crtloc_lng":"72.976631"},{"user_id":"86","crtloc_lat":"33.6971‌​17","crtloc_lng":"72.976631"}]`

now i want to get the data in result array and show that data in android.for example i want to use all the(user_id) from that array

Comment: I think your `json` response is an `JSONObject` not `JSONArray`. Add your json response.

Comment: post sample of your json

Comment: this is my json @karim mohsen

Comment: add in your question. remove from comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you got this error because `jArray.getJSONObject(0);` when i = 0 it's an array not an Object

your Json `[[],{"user_id":"77","crtloc_lat":"34.769638","crtloc_lng":"72.361145"},...]`

So `jArray.getJSONObject(0);` is `[]` **not an object** `{"user_id":"77","crtloc_lat":"34.769638","crtloc_lng":"72.361145"}`

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this post on how to execute [GET/POST/MULTIPART POST requests](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-get-post-and-multipart-post-requests/) in android and then use that post to see how to [parse your JSON data into pojo(s)](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-parsing-json-data-with-gson/).
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error:type `org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray` is thrown when you try to fetch a JSONObject in the place of an array. An exception will also be thrown if you try to fetch empty objects so please check your code for empties.

**start by**

```
    $abc="";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
if(!empty($row['user_id'])&&!empty($row['crtloc_lat'])&&!empty($row['crtloc_lng'])){
    $abc=$abc.$row['user_id'].",".$row['crtloc_lat'].",".$row['crtloc_lng']."~";
    }       
    }
```

**Then**

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {    
     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
     JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
     String jsonString = jArray.getString("crtloc_lat");//Use a key here
     stringArray[i] = e.toString();
     Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "yourrrrs"+stringArray[0],Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
     mylist.add(map);
                }
```

Comment: tried it also but getting the same error:jsonArray cannot be converted to json object